# Data transfer slows over time in sending data to a WCF service from WCF client (NET.TCP binding)

Tags: .net, wcf, performance, tcp

I have a WCF client that establishes a connection to a WCF server. When i start my host app the client works fine and receives and responds to requests in a timely fashion. But after about a minute or so and with increased load the process slows to a crawl.

Ive traced the problem to the time it takes to send a response back to the WCF server. Sending just simple text (not more than 2 Kb) is taking 10-15 seconds and sometimes even longer than that.

The WCF server itself is running perfectly fine (as far as i know)

Are there any specific setting that i can tweak that might speed up the throughput or correct the situation ?

The services communiate with net.tcp binding. Here is my config settings

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_Comms" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                sendTimeout="00:01:00" transactionFlow="false" 
                transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="500"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536"
                maxConnections="500" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
                    maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false"/>
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"
                        protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://a.b.com:9150/Comms/"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Comms"
            contract="Outside.Comms" name="NetTcpBinding_Comms">
            <identity>
                <dns value="a.b.com"/>
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: unfortunately not as the client does not want me to do that. The code itself is simple and is just a standard net.tcp wcf client. The delay is during the process of sending data back to the wcf server. I basically record the time, make the call to send the data back to the server and then record the time and for small data the time that passes is > 10s. When the app starts up this is not the behaviour and the time taken is quick (order of ms). Its only after a few minutes that the issue occurs.

Comment: Turn on wcf tracing on both server and client and check when the delay occures.